# Different behavior between Dbeaver and OSD clients with dates

Tags: oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbeaver

I use Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0

When doing this query :

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (DATE '2005-11-25') IN ('25/11/05') THEN
        'TRUE'
    ELSE
        'FALSE'
    END
FROM DUAL;
```

I get `FALSE` from Oracle SQL Developer 21.4.1.349 (French version) and `TRUE` from DBeaver 21.1.4.202108020335 (French version).

I understand that I compare a date with a string, so in my opinion the result should be `FALSE`, but that may me implementation-dependant.

How does it come that Oracle answers differently in those situations ? Does DBeaver do a preprocessing on dates before submitting the request?

Comment: You compare a `DATE` value with a **string**, that's always bad. Compare `DATE` values with a `DATE` or compare a `VARCHAR2` with a `VARCHAR2`, don't mix any.

Comment: 'French version' doesn't mean much; what are the NLS settings in both clients? Presumably NLS_DATE_FORMAT is different - I'd guess one with YY and the other with YYYY?

Comment: Indeed. We get from `SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter ='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';` the value `DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS` in OSD and `DD/MM/RR` in DBeaver. Thanks!

Comment: If your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS` then `TO_CHAR(CAST('25/11/05' AS DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` will output `0005-11-25 00:00:00` and be the wrong century. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=372fdefacb4b540331d27b2f2eeb05a4) Do **NOT** rely on implicit string conversions as you will get errors like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are comparing a date to a string, you are causing the string to be implicitly converted to a date, using your session's NLS settings. Those may be derived from your locale, or may be set explicitly by your client, e.g. through preferences.

If `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is is set to 'DD/MM/YYYY' then '25/11/05' is converted to 0005-11-25, so the comparison is false. If it is set to 'DD/MM/YY' (or 'DD/MM/RR', or 'DD/MM/RRRR') then it is converted to 2005-11-25, so the comparison is true.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b9f36acb89aab01a2c41545f24bbaa8)

You should not rely on implicit conversions, or NLS settings - since you can't control the environment of whoever runs your code.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` the session is using.

Oracle will implicitly convert your query to the equivalent of:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN DATE '2005-11-25' IN (
              TO_DATE(
                '25/11/05',
                (SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
              )
            )
       THEN 'TRUE'
       ELSE 'FALSE'
       END
FROM   DUAL;
```

As it relies on an implicit conversion from string to date so Oracle will use the session's date format in the conversion.

---

For example:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/RR';

SELECT CASE WHEN DATE '2005-11-25' IN ('25/11/05')
       THEN 'TRUE'
       ELSE 'FALSE'
       END
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs: `TRUE`

But:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

SELECT CASE WHEN DATE '2005-11-25' IN ('25/11/05')
       THEN 'TRUE'
       ELSE 'FALSE'
       END
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs: `FALSE`

You can see why using:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST('25/11/05' AS DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs `0005-11-25 00:00:00` and is the 1st century, and not the 21st century, as the implicit conversion uses the `DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS` format model and expects a 4-digit year and gets the input `05` and assumes it to be a correct value of 5 AD rather than the 5th year of the current century (which you would get with the `YY` format model).

---

The best solution is to not rely on implicit string-to-date conversions.

Either using date literals:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN DATE '2005-11-25' IN (DATE '2005-11-25')
       THEN 'TRUE'
       ELSE 'FALSE'
       END
FROM   DUAL;
```

Or, providing an explicit format model for the conversion:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN DATE '2005-11-25' IN (TO_DATE('25/11/05', 'DD/MM/RR'))
       THEN 'TRUE'
       ELSE 'FALSE'
       END
FROM   DUAL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=49005d1bb671c324c3819b84a1dd1378)*